# How to download and rename images parallely in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, file-get-contents

Hi I have created a script to download images and to rename from a url. The links and name are stored in a database. The database looks like this:-

```
id      name       url 
1       abcd       http://www.abcd.com/a.jpeg
```

I am running a following script to download and renaming the images.:-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$results = $gtl->query($sql);  
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
   $n = $row['name'];
   $url = $row['url'];
   $name = $n.'.jpeg';

   $path = "images/";  

   if ($url != NULL) {
     $get_image = file_get_contents($url);

     if ($http_response_header != NULL) {
        $get_file = $path . $name;
        file_put_contents($get_file, $get_image);
    }
}
```

The following code works well but consumes a lot of time. **I have tried using cURL but it has similar speed**. Since there are over 300 images that needs to be downloaded. It would be a great if anyone can suggest a way to fasten the process. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why is the duration important at all? This sounds like a very questionable design. Such tasks are typically done in background, obviously independent of a browser request. In such case the absolute duration is without interest if within reasonable limits.

Comment: @arkascha It is important as I intend to create an efficent script which downloads images in minumn time possible.

Comment: Ok, sure, if that is your only concern and since you do not answer to the _why_ at all: then good luck, go! Once you have your working implementation please share it here! We are especially interested in how you get around the bandwidth limitation of the network link and the maximum output of the remote system.